Elasticsearch intervals vs span near?
I want to filter by the distance between two terms both ordered and unordered
Seems both intervals and span query can solve this.
However at first glance span query is a nightmare to use with other queries because a span query can contain only other span query.
So intervals query is enough for me?
Or what is the advantage to use span query?

Interval queries are meant to be the long-term replacement for the span queries. They were added exactly to improve the user experience. If they work for you, you should continue to use them.
